# Calculating the expected value of the amount of same numbers chosen by two people.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, independence, expected-value

so I've been stuck all day on one question and I have no idea what to.

This is the problem: Two people choose from a set of integers ranging from 2 to 100.(so 99 different integers) One person chooses 49 times and the other 50 times. However they do it independently the question is what is the expected number of times that these two people have chosen the same integers from the list. 
Also they will not choose the same number twice. So both will have a list of numbers made up of distinct integers.

I know how to calculate expected values however in this context I'm so confused that I have no idea how to even begin. Any idea or help will be very much appreciated.

EDIT: This is the exact questioning of the problem and it has to do with TSP(Traveling salesman's problem)

On day 4, you and your colleague randomly select 50 (for you) and 49 (for your
colleague) of the remaining cities 2; : : : ; 100. You make your choices independently
of each other, so it is very likely that there are cities that you visit both. What is
the expected number of cities that you visit both, not including city 1 ?
(Hint: the answer does not have to be an integer number. You can rst consider
the situation of one city that you visit.)

Comment: What do you mean by "chosen the same integers"?  Do you mean the expected number of integers that have been chosen by both?  Or something else?

Comment: If person 1 chooses 49 integers from 2,3...100 then he has a list of 49 integers. So if he were to choose for example 6 and 48 other integers that person 2 who chooses 50 numbers from the same set of integers ranging from 2,3...100 then there is also a chance he would choose 6. Now the question is what is the expected value for the amount of integers which are both chosen by person 1 and 2.

Comment: drhab has answered the question, then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $i=2,3,\dots,100$ let $X_i$ take value $1$ if number $i$ is chosen by both and let $X_i$ take value $0$ otherwise.

Then the number of numbers chosen by both is: $$X=\sum_{i=2}^{100}X_i$$

Now find $\mathbb EX$ by applying linearity of expectation and symmetry.

Comment: I don't quite understand how you can apply linearity of expectation and symmetry since one can only know whether the value Xi is 1 if it is chosen by both so how does one apply it, also both persons will not choose the same integer twice when choosing from 2,3...100. So their 'lists' of integers are all distinct integers. Which decreases the probability of an integer to be chosen after an integer has been  chosen. So it goes 1/99 to 1/98.. and so on

Comment: Do you agree that the probability that (for exampe) number $17$ is chosen by both equals $\frac{49}{99}\frac{50}{99}$ (so that $\mathbb EX_{17}=\frac{49}{99}\frac{50}{99}$)? The probability the first-mentioned person chooses $17$ is $\frac{49}{99}$ and the probability that the second chooses $17$ is $\frac{50}{99}$. Next to that there is independence so the probability that both choose $17$ is the product of these probabilities.

Comment: Yes that I understand so by that knowledge it would simply mean to apply the formula E(X) = Σxf (x) which is what you've mentioned already or did you mean something else?

Comment: We can do that for every $i$ and find $\mathbb EX_i=1P(X_i=1)+0P(X_i=0)=\frac{49}{99}\frac{50}{99}$ for $i=2,\dots100$. Then by symmetry $\mathbb EX=99\times\frac{49}{99}\frac{50}{99}$